# what token should be used for publishing news feed to app user's wall

Tags: publish, access-token, facebook-access-token

I have a question about which access token should be used for publishing news feed to user's wall via PHP SDK.

Basically, there is a delay, let say 7 days, between user connected to the app and the news feed get published. My understanding is we can store the 60-day long-lived token into database first and then make use of it 7 days later.

However, the article here suggested that it is possible to use the app token (with no expiration time) to publish news need.

So, my questions are

1. Which token should I use under the current scenario?
2. Which one will be safer to use?
3. Is there any risk of using either long-lived token or app token?

Thank you very much!